# Numerical range of $2 \times 2$ - matrix

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I am reading Chapter 22 of the book "A Hilbert space problem book", written by Paul R. Halmos.The topic is about "Numerical range".

According to the book, the numerical range of an operator $A: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{H}$, in which $\mathbb{H}$ is a Hilbert space, is defined by
$$W(A) = \left \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mid  z = \left<Af, f \right> \text{where} \|f\| =1\right\}.$$

In example, the author gives matrix  A
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\ 
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
And he claims that the numerical range of $A$ is the closed elliptical disc with foci 0, 1, two axes are 1 and $\sqrt{2}$.

I dont know how he can give that answer.

What I tried is the following.

Let $f=(f_1,f_2)$ be some vector in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

Calculate casually, we obtain
$W(A) = \left \{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid z = f_1 f_2 + f_2^2 \text{ where } f_1^2 + f_2^2 =1\right \}$.

Could you please give me the equation of desired elliptical disc? I tried many times but not effective.

Thank you in advace

Comment: I presume $\Bbb H = \Bbb C^2$ here, and so $f\in\Bbb C^2$ and the condition is $z=(f_1+f_2)\bar f_2$ with $|f_1|^2+|f_2|^2 = 1$. If you work with real vectors, you end up only with a closed interval in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: That's right. $\mathbb{H} = \mathbb{C} ^2$. I could not imagine how the orbit of $z=f_1f_2+f_2^2$ can be a closed elliptical disc.

Comment: You haven't made the rest of the corrections. You are using the hermitian inner product on $\Bbb C^2$. Basically, you take the image of the $3$-dimensional sphere $|f_1|^2+|f_2|^2 = 1$ and you do get an elliptical disk. You might try this: Set $f_1=wf_2$ and then check that you get $z=\dfrac{1+w}{1+|w|^2}$. The image of that mapping will be the elliptical disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of the calculation. As I suggested before, write $f_1=wf_2$ for $w\in\Bbb C$. The condition that $|f_1|^2+|f_2|^2=1$ translates to $|f_2|^2(1+|w|^2)=1$. Now, we're considering
$$z=f_1\bar f_2 + |f_2|^2 = |f_2|^2(1+w) = \frac{1+w}{1+|w|^2}.$$

Set $w=te^{i\theta}$. Then you can check that $z=z(t,\theta)=\dfrac1{1+t^2}\big(1+t\cos\theta,t\sin\theta\big)$. As a map from $\Bbb R_+\times [0,2\pi]$ to $\Bbb R^2$, a little calculation shows $z$ drops rank when $2t\cos\theta = 1-t^2$. With a bit of algebra, you can check that, substituting that relation, we get $z=(x,y)$ where
$$x=\frac12\cdot\frac{3-t^2}{1+t^2} \quad\text{and}\quad y^2 = \left(\frac t{1+t^2}\right)^2\left(1-\frac14\left(\frac1t-t\right)^2\right).$$

I don't quite see how to do the algebra pro-actively, but you can in fact substitute and check that this parametric curve gives you precisely
$$2(x-\tfrac12)^2 + 4 y^2 = 1,$$
which is the ellipse with axes $1$ and $\sqrt 2$ and centered at $x=1/2$, and this has foci at precisely $z=0$ and $z=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Your proof is very clear. However, I confuse the word "drop ranks" in the sentence "a little calculation shows $z$ drops rank when $2t \cos{\theta} = 1 - t^2$. Could you please explain in more detail the aim of this setting?

Comment: The Jacobian matrix  of the mapping $z(t,\theta)$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix. Where this matrix is nonsingular ($\det\ne 0$), $z$ is an open mapping; the edge of the image will come from the points where the matrix is singular ($\det = 0$). That's where I got the equation.